# Fill from a specific point using izip_longest

Tags: python, icc

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/python

from itertools import chain, izip_longest
def filltape(n):    
  numlist = list(range(-(2*n)+1, (2*n)+1))  
  alphalist= list("".join('BA' for i in xrange(n)))
  print list(chain(*izip_longest(numlist, alphalist, fillvalue=' ')))
filltape(4)
```

And the output is:

```
 [-7, 'B', -6, 'A', -5, 'B', -4, 'A', -3, 'B', -2, 'A', -1, 'B', 0,'A', 1, ' ', 2, ' ', 3, ' ', 4, ' ', 5, ' ', 6, ' ', 7, ' ', 8, ' ']
```

I am not able to figure out how to print the shorter list from halfway into the longer list, basically I want the output to look like:

```
[-7, ' ', -6, ' ', -5, ' ', -4, ' ', -3, ' ', -2, ' ', -1, ' ', 0, ' ', 1, 'B', 2, 'A', 3, 'B', 4, 'A', 5, 'B', 6, 'A', 7, 'B', 8, 'A']
```

Background: I am trying to solve [this problem](http://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/problems/icpc2014.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this (not the most efficient though) is to reverse the lists, zip, and reverse the zip:

```
>>> def filltape(n):
...   numlist = list(range(-(2*n)+1, (2*n)+1))
...   alphalist= list("".join('BA' for i in xrange(n)))
...   print list(chain(*izip_longest(alphalist[::-1],numlist[::-1], fillvalue=' ')))[::-1]
...
>>> filltape(4)
[-7, ' ', -6, ' ', -5, ' ', -4, ' ', -3, ' ', -2, ' ', -1, ' ', 0, ' ', 1, 'B', 2, 'A', 3, 'B', 4, 'A', 5, 'B', 6, 'A', 7, 'B', 8, 'A']
```

Comment: That's possible, but that is the output he wanted in the question.

Comment: I know what am trying out right now is/may not be the way to solve the ACM question but the output I wanted is achieved with fredtantini's answer, thanks!